# keyboard compose sequences with "dead_caron"

Tags: keyboard-layout

My file `/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose` reads along the lines:

```
<dead_caron> <1>      : "₁"   onesubscript        # SUBSCRIPT ONE
```

I have a more or less standard qwerty keyboard with US keys.  What is `dead_caron`, how do I type one, and where are these keys  defined?

EDIT

I am aware that I can define any sequences manually.  I would like to redefine dead_caron which is already used by hundreds of sequences already.

Comment: Then you may want to modify the keyboard layout you are using. Which layout is it?

Comment: I am switching between several, most of the time it is "lv".

Comment: You can edit `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/lv` and replace a *Latvian* symbol, which you typically don't use, with `dead_caron`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/lv` file for editing and replace the line

```
key <AB10> {[ slash,        question,   slash,          abovedot        ]};
```

with

```
key <AB10> {[ slash,        question,   dead_caron,         abovedot        ]};
```

That would make `dead_caron` available via

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>

Comment: Thank you.  Is this achievable without changing system files, just by overriding something in ~/.XCompose?  Otherwise this solution is not carried other with system upgrades.

Comment: @punund: There may be a more complex solution, without changing a package file, but I don't know how. After all this trivial change isn't very hard to redo at upgrade, is it? As regards `~/.XCompose`, it makes use of various symbols which are available via the keyboard layout you are using; it does not alter the keyboard layout.

Answer (score 1):

It's a diacritic for typing e.g. **ǎ**, and only available on certain keyboard layouts. The basic *English (US)* layout is not one of those, but `dead_caron` can be typed using the *English (US, intl., with dead keys)* keyboard layout:

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> followed by <kbd>Space</kbd> => ˇ

<kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> followed by <kbd>1</kbd> => ₁

Keyboard layouts are located in the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` directory. The US ones, for instance, are in the `us` file in that directory.

*Edit:*

If your goal is to type subscript numbers, while the keyboard layout you use does not include the `dead_caron` symbol, it's simpler to [define a compose key](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html#compose) and then do:

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>_</kbd> followed by <kbd>1</kbd> -> ₁

<kbd>Compose</kbd> followed by <kbd>_</kbd> followed by <kbd>2</kbd> -> ₂

etc.

Comment: Thank you. None of my configured layouts is "us", is there a way to add a definition of "dead_caron" to my custom .XCompose so that I can take advantage of definitions from the big system Compose file?

Comment: @punund: You need neither the US Compose file nor `~/.XCompose` for that. Many of those rules, including the one for typing ₁, are integrated in GTK. Maybe you'd better explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: Le's say I want to achieve subscript one "₁" as defined.

Comment: RightAlt+Shift are probably redefined by my layout and won't work.  I would like to define dead_caron before inclusion of the big US Compose file so that I can use sequences defined there.

Comment: @punund: Please see my edited answer.

Comment: See my updated question.